# Analog vs digital version of Butterworth filter in SciPy

Tags: python, filter, scipy, digital, digital-analog-converter

I have a question about the analog and digital versions of the Butterworth filter in SciPy. I tried two things to get a **digital** Butterworth filter:

- Getting an analog filter by [`scipy.signal.butter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) with `analog=True`, and then using `scipy.signal.bilinear` to transform it into a digital filter.
- Directly getting from the function `scipy.signal.butter` with `analog=False`.

I got different results from the two methods. Should I expect same result from these two approaches? My code:

```py
from scipy import signal

b1, a1 = signal.butter(1, 1, 'high', analog=True)
print("analog filter: ", [b1, a1])

fs = 100

b2, a2 = signal.bilinear(b1, a1, fs)
print("digital filter from bilinear transformation of analog filter: ", [b2, a2])


b, a = signal.butter(1, 1*2/fs, 'high', analog=False)
print("digital filter: ", [b, a])
```

Output:

```py
analog filter:  [array([1., 0.]), array([1., 1.])]
digital filter from bilinear transformation of analog filter:  [array([ 0.99502488, -0.99502488]), array([ 1.        , -0.99004975])]
digital filter:  [array([ 0.96953125, -0.96953125]), array([ 1.        , -0.93906251])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just get the answer to this question by reading some materials about digital filters [a note about digital filter](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Esjrob/Teaching/SP/l6.pdf)

The bilinear transformation [image: formula] between analogue filter and digital filter gives us a non-linear relationship between the analogue frequency [image: formula] and digital frequency [image: formula] as introduced in the material.

[image: formula]

Thus, if a digital filter is needed, directly design it from `scipy.signal.butter` is better.

Comment: Are you implying that the third call in your question has a linear relationship?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, as written in the equation, the relationship contains a tangent function, which means the relationship is nonlinear